# Как правильно записать регулярное выражение (PHP, MongoDB)?

Tags: php

Помогите составить регулярку , имеется такой код я помощью которого я фильтрую запросы mongoDb

```
$argumentValue = new Regex('^' . $argumentValue. '$', 'i');
```

$argumentValue = .**a6.*;
Нужно экранировать вторую звездочку

Comment: *Требуется учитывать поиск по символу `*`*  - поясните эту фразу.

Comment: Заодно уточните, что же находится в переменной `$argumentValue`.

Comment: @Akina у меня в mongodb имеются записи у которых есть символ (*)
Мне нужно как то экранировать этот символ, чтобы я мог осуществлять по нему поиск

Comment: `preg_quote($argumentValue)`

Comment: @Akina в $argumentValue  находится вот такая запись .**a6.*

Comment: А чем вас `\*` не устроило?